# How to look ahead and order a queryset in django?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

I'm developing a chat app. The models are:

```
User:
name
```

and

```
Message:
user = ForeignKeyField(User, related_name="messages"),
message,
time
```

Now, There are just two users in the database. Lets say the message objects are like:

> msg1: user1: "hello"
>
> msg2: user1: "how are you?"
>
> msg3: user2: "I'm fine."
>
> msg4: user1: "what's up?"
>
> msg5: user2: "nothing much."
>
> msg6: user2: "Hmm."

Now I need to get the messages in an order as (let's say json):

`{user1:[msg1, msg2], user2:[msg3], user1:[msg4], user2:[msg5, msg6]}`

I need it to be filtered in a queryset something like:

```
Message.objects.filter(....).order(....)
```

***used json here for understanding.

- How could this be done?
- Are there any drawbacks?
- I am to render this in the template afterwards. So, Is it possible to order the same inside a template using for loop?

Ok. If this can't be implemented in a queryset. Then let the one below be a sample template:

```
<div class="chat">
  <div class="photo">
  </div>
  <div class="msg"></div>
  <div class="msg"></div>
</div>
```

How can I implement it:

```
{% for msg in msgs %}
   <div class="chat">
     <div class="photo">
     </div>
     <div class="msg">msg.message</div>
     <div class="msg">msg.message</div>//this should happen only if msg.user is same as previous msg.user
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

So, how? I know django's `ifchanged` control. But I'm not able to use it.

Comment: This does not make much sense, since a dictionary can only contain a key once, hre your dictionary contains `user1`, and `user2` twice.

Comment: You can however use a list of for example tuples (well in JSON it is then a list of lists). Where each tuple contains 2 elements; the user, and a list of messages.

Comment: Furthermore it is not clear to me what `msg1` is supposed to contain. A string (the message)? And then what is `user1`? An `int`eger (the id)?

Comment: No. don't think about json. I have used json for understanding. I need a queryset.

Comment: But a queryset typically does not contain keys that map to lists (unless the *fields* are lists).

Comment: `msg1` is a `Message` object. I have given the `Message model` above. Please check. `user1` is a `User` object.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem updated please check.

Comment: then you probably need to perform some logic in the view to group the messages together.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above does not make much sense since a dictionary (both in Python and in JSON), can contain a key only *once*. You can thus not have a dictionary that contains `user1` twice.

We can however use a iterable that contains 2-tuples: a tuple that contains a `user` as the left item, and the "*burst*" of messages in the second. So something like:

```
[
  (user1, [msg1, msg2]),
  (user2, [msg3]),
  (user1, [msg4]),
  (user2, [msg5, msg6])
]
```

We can do this by adding some processing in the view. As query, we first sort on the `Message`s by `time`, and we fetch the `user`s as well. Next we use `itertools.groupby` to make groups per user, like:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import attrgetter

qs = Message.objects.select_related('user').order_by('time')
all_msgs = [(u, list(ms)) for (u, ms) in groupby(qs, attrgetter('user'))]
return render(request, 'template.html', {'all_msgs': all_msgs})
```

In the template we then render over the 2-tuples, and then over the messages individually:

```
{% for user, msgs in all_msgs %}
  <div class="chat">
    <div class="photo">{{ user.photo }}
    </div>
    {% for msg in msgs %}
    <div class="msg">msg.message</div>
    {% endfor %}
  </div>
{% endfor %}
```

where in the `for` loops, you of course still have to fill in the data. For example `{{ user.photo }}` (given that exists).

Comment: I can't go on saying thanks again and again. You are soooo helpful. You got a fan now. I wish I should be like you. May I know how you learnt these?